# Seagate Backup Plus Portable drive can't be found on my computer

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, data-recovery

I'm trying to recover/troubleshoot my external hard drive (Seagate Backup Plus), for some reason it had just stop working. I'm on OSX and trying to troubleshoot it using my Windows XP running on VMWare because it's in NTFS format.

So far, here's what I have found out. My VM Ware is able to recognise the drive but it can't be detected in any part of windows.

[image: VMWare Image]

Here, It's not available in **My Computer** and under **Disk Management**.

**My Computer**
[image: MyComputer Image]

**Disk Management**
[image: DiskManager Image]

I'm guessing this would be a hardware failure than software. I've tried to plug it on other computer and it's having the same symptoms.My OSX can't also read the drive even running with Paragon.

Any ideas for solution and troubleshooting?

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding in NTFS support for MacOS, [there's a guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/236055/how-to-write-to-ntfs-drives-on-a-mac/).

All of these are viable options, and if you really want to go for it, you can use the third option,

> #### Apple’s Experimental NTFS-Write Support:
>
> Mac OS X includes experimental 
>   support for writing to NTFS drives. However, it’s off by default and requires 
>   some messing around in the terminal to enable it. It isn’t guaranteed to work 
>   properly and could potentially cause problems with your NTFS file system — we 
>   really don’t recommend using this.

As mentioned in the article, it's not recommended to do it if you don't know what you're doing. 
I don't know if it will work or not, but give it a go.